# Change expire time on configuration yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I have this settings.yaml here on a python project that I will use it for google auth.

The configuration is working fine, but I have a problem, because it is generating a token that will expire after 1 hour.

How can I configure it, so I can change the expiration time to a bigger value?

```
client_config_backend: settings
    client_config:
      client_id: <client_id>
      client_secret: <client_secret>
    
    save_credentials: True
    save_credentials_backend: file
    save_credentials_file: credentials.json
    
    get_refresh_token: True
    
    oauth_scope:
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that is not possible,

Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.